# Restrict access to WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

How to make only certain IP addresses allowed to access my website. Currently I'm using wordpress. I want to make it so that if the user IP is not on the list the page will redirect to another site. Please help me.

Comment: sorry..i'm new to this site..

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an Apache server (and `AllowOverride` is enabled) you could do this by making a file called `.htaccess` in the directory you want to restrict access to and enter:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4 # replace this with your IP
```

Alternatively you could do this in your main Apache configuration, with a `<Directory>` directive but you won't be able to do this if you're on shared hosting. (Bit of a mini-assumption there, hence the .htaccess solution)

There are also other methods, for example editing your PHP to check the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` value and `die` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this WordPress plugin called [Restricted Site Access](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/).